# MVC 4 SQL Server Express exception after being inactive for a few minutes

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, sqlexception

I'm new to MVC so I started my project using the basic template. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 with an already existing database to handle logins and registrations (instead of EF with SQL Server Express).

I have already made the changes needed for working with an existing database.
The only problem is that after I login to the web app and stay inactive for a few minutes and refresh the admin page I get a SQL Server error

> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error

Please note that after logout and login the admin page shown without that exception.

Even after I login from a different browser while the other shows the exception, ctrl + F5 and the exception is gone, like the login recreates the connection.

1. Why am I getting this exception
2. Why `SQLEXPRESS`?

Bear in mind, the SQL Server service is running so it's not the issue.

Any ideas?

**Stack trace:**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6573870
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6600312
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6602662
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6603203
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +816
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +61
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +953
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6610951
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
>      System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +98

>

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
>
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +4570794
>      System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +229
>      System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +908

Answer (score 0):

Double Check it is running. I have this when I switch between servers.
Secondly ensure connection string is correct, no typos, server name is correct, etc.

It has to one of these, connection string or service not running. Restarting your machine is an option.

Press windows short cut  Win+R to open the run window, or any other way you can get to it
Type in Services as in your screen shot below. This brings up the services dialog. Look for SQL Express Server and Select it. Then Click on Start link to start the Server. As is second screen shot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checked it again bro... I have stop, pause, restart links... It's running